# Should we close-vote questions that we cannot reproduce on our machines?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, minimal-reproducible-example

This is about the **V** in [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

## Premise

You see a standard question for debugging support. Done right and [by the book](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it has a problem statement, sample input, expected output, actual output and a sample code that compiles and expects input and gives output.

## Situation

You copy and paste the code into your IDE, run it with the given input and... it does *not* reproduce the output described by the OP as a problem. Maybe "it works" on your machine, maybe it exhibits another weird behavior. The OP said it prints "3", but it crashed on your machine. Or maybe the OP said it crashes, but when you run it, it correctly displays the results.

## Possible Actions

[Somebody said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364303/2060725) that the question should be closed as

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

since when you tried to verify it on your machine, you couldn't reproduce the problem and it therefor is missing the V in MCVE, and no V means there is no complete MCVE, which in turn is a close-reason.

Personally, I have been bitten by enough bugs that I know that things can work on one computer, but not on another, only work when you are connected to a domain even though your code as written should not care, fail until you have installed the service pack, fail in your specific time zone, fail for a username with non-ASCII characters, or a myriad of other reasons why it might behave differently on *my* machine.

My first instinct would be to write a comment informing the OP that it behaves differently on my machine and if the OP is interested, work out what the difference in our machines is. So when somebody told me to close vote that question instead, I was confused.

**So what is the correct way to proceed here? Should a question with code that I can *run* but that does not reproduce the problem on my machine be closed as not having an MCVE?**

Comment: I wouldn't recommend closure on a lot of performance questions. Many of those are specific to a line of processors which not everybody has. Furthermore, they may change from generation to generation. In those cases, the primary reason why someone would not be able to reproduce is simply that they have the wrong hardware.

Comment: No.  But there is a subset of askers that post fake snippets in their questions.  You can usually tell, either from not being formatted by their text editor or missing crucial details.  Bam!

Answer (score 17):

You should cast a close vote in these cases only if you feel that *not doing so would result in someone else likely wasting their time*. There's no real blanket flowchart sort of answer to it other than use your best judgement based on your knowledge of the language being used.

Undefined behavior? Possibly a compiler error you're not reproducing because they failed to mention it's not x86? It's possible that someone else might just be able to figure out what the OP didn't think was relevant enough to mention (which might, indeed, have seemed inconsequential as they considered the scope of what might be wrong).

If you're *sure* that anyone else spending time looking into it would certainly mean time wasted, then vote to close it and leave a comment just in case there's something the OP didn't include perhaps in haste in writing the question.

If you think something like "This seems weird, but maybe someone might be able to look at the intermediate compiler output and get a better sense of it" or "maybe I'll try this on ARM through an emulator later" -- leave it open, leave a comment and, well, leave a little time to come back to it later and see what it was.

But don't just close it as "Works on my machine" unless you're *really* sure :)

Comment: I would err toward closing as no repro rather than no MCVE, and comment as such, affording the OP the opportunity to revisit the question. Ideally we could retract our close vote and then re-cast it as a No MCVE if that comes to light but the system does not allow us to recast close votes when we retract a prior one, unfortunately.

Comment: If someone complains "I cannot enter a string, plz halp", my default comment is something like "check if your keyboard is connected properly".

Answer (score 15):

I don't think there is a clear answer, it will always depend on the question (and the technology).

When talking about very simple basic language feature questions, similar to

> Why does this Java code throw a invalid smurf exception
>
> ```
> some code here
> ```

and it runs on your computer without any problems, I would vote to close.

For another category of questions it isn't that simple. I'm mostly active in the computer graphics related tags and here it is not uncommon that an application works perfectly fine on one PC and not on another one. Sometimes it is caused by driver issues, different hardware, or invoking undefined behavior. Also in C++ you can do a lot of stupid stuff that sometimes works and sometimes not (for example, reading from uninitialized memory).

For these questions, I wouldn't vote<sub>1</sub> to close as long as the problem persists on OPs environment and they can tell us if changing code makes a difference or not.

<sub>1 Exception: Questions of this form: My teacher says that my application doesn't work on the lab-PC, but it runs fine on my home PC. I don't have access to that machine, please help me. Reason: If noone, including op can tell if a answer is working, it doesn't really make sense to guess around.</sub>

Comment: The fact that *you* can't reproduce the problem doesn't mean that the OP can't reproduce it.  The close reason  you mention exists for issues that *the question author* can no longer reproduce, not for cases where they have not provided an accurate example for others to be able to reproduce it.  The close reason that states that questions, "must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" is specifically for cases where the OP can still reproduce the problem, but they just haven't given *us* enough info.

Answer (score 9):

If you're unable to reproduce, but OP states that he can consistently reproduce the issue, then there can be a problem with the C, the question is incomplete since it doesn't provide enough information to reproduce the problem, or V, the problem is not verifiable.

Honestly, I'd say any MCVE that is *complete* should be *verifiable* as well. If it's not verifiable, that's likely because relevant details are missing (it's not complete).

This consideration:

> My first instinct would be to write a comment informing the OP that it behaves differently on my machine and if the OP is interested, work out what the difference in our machines is.

Implies the example is not *complete*, which in turn makes it not verifiable. but the main problem is the incompleteness, as I see it.

Closing an incomplete question, or asking for more information instead, is a difficult consideration. I often ask for more information, then revisit in an hour or so to cast a close vote if none has been provided.

However, I'd take great care in closing non-reproducible problems, as someone else might be able to reproduce them (the OP probably was, else he hadn't asked the question). It might be version-dependent, OS dependent, driver-related, localization settings related, or a number of other things that vary between computer to computer, depending on the question.

Comment: This is a situation where asking a few clarifying questions would be preferable to a straight-up close vote.

Comment: @theMayer That's your opinion. But take with you that if the question gets closed, and then OP makes a substantial edit, that puts it back in the reopen queue. Also, you can retract your close votes. As said, I'd probably ask for clarification, wait a bit, and then cast a close vote if nothing happens, also because most activity/answers come in the first few hours of posting a question.

Comment: I've usually found that once a question is placed on hold, it makes more sense to reformulate and ask anew than to try to re-open. By the time it's closed, there are often multiple downvotes, and as a rule, I usually do not open up, and almost never answer down-voted questions. I have to believe others act in a similar manner.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your post. I actually didn't make it all the way to the end, since it seems to ramble a bit... but once I did, I see that you more or less made my point.

Comment: _"...preferable to a straight-up close vote"_ [How soon should I vote to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026)

Answer (score 2):

I can talk about 2 domains I'm following: C & Python

*For starters, if the code isn't pastable in a REPL or text file and is missing parts, yes, I'd vote to close as no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and move on.*

Now, let's suppose that OP took some time to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (or what he/she thinks is a [mcve]).

Some C/C++ codes invoke undefined behaviour, so even if you cannot reproduce, you *could* (by staring at the code hard enough until it confesses) spot the one-off error that triggers the undefined behaviour.

So you cannot reproduce, but you can see that there's a problem (very often questions get side comments about how `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour or "don't use `gets`", or "your array is too small" even if it's not the main issue or doesn't seem to be..)

In those cases, you also want to make OP specify their compiler *and* version. This example could not be reproduced on gcc 6, but could on earlier versions: [Casting to union field yields to conversion warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195421/casting-to-union-field-yields-to-conversion-warning). After OP specifies the version, the problem *is* reproducible. It just depends on how far you want to go to install a prehistoric version on your machine if you don't have it handy (or let others test for you). I wouldn't vote to close if I didn't take extra effort to reproduce in OP context.

In the python area, it's the same thing: I often use python 3.4 (I got all packages installed on it), and there are subtle differences with python 3.6 for instance, or different versions of external packages. OP tags the question [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and sometimes [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) and it's often enough. Who knows the slight behaviour differences between the 2? Does that usually matter?

Unless it's a clear case of OP incompetence who thinks that "python `if` statement doesn't work", if I cannot reproduce, I first ping OP saying "cannot reproduce" and make him/her edit to add the exact python version. If I don't have the version handy, I can try to reproduce on `repl.it`, or I can move on, but in that case I'm not voting.

Another specific python issue is OP redefining a built-in, and then getting strange "object xxx isn't subscriptable" or stuff like that. In those cases we don't have full context, but with enough hindsight, if we're sure that the issue comes from that redefinition, the question is even answerable, else vote to close and let OP restart his/her IDE so the problem goes away.

Comment: In my experience, non-reproducible python questions are often a result of retyping instead of copy and paste, and either adding *or deleting) a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such questions are a big concern. If the code is runnable and produces something different, informing the questioner about it is for sure useful. Closing would potentially deprive him of the chance to get an answer from someone with a similar problem.

Since SO does not allow to add a large amount of data into questions, by which one could verify the complete system the code runs on, it is impossible to create entirely complete and verifiable examples. There are always assumptions about the system in the game, and we should allow for questions which cannot be answered by 99% of the people, but potentially can by one single user, if one's lucky.
Usually such questions get answered some months later when someone happens to run into the same combination of unfortunate prerequesites as the questioner but found a way out.
(As an example, I have a GUI which errors at startup if the system's standard printer is not connected. You'll never find those errors if you closed such questions immediately.)
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183536/windows-python-matplotlib-latex-flashing-cmd-windows) is a real world example on SO.

Apart, the review queue currently does not even manage to close those questions which *do* lack a runnable code; so it would be worth putting effort into closing those rather than discussing the edge cases.

Answer (score -4):

> My first instinct would be to write a comment informing the OP that it behaves differently on my machine and if the OP is interested, work out what the difference in our machines is. So when somebody told me to close vote that question instead, I was confused.

The whole premise of closure is that when a question cannot be answered, as is, it is closed to prevent people from posting low quality answers to a question that is not currently answerable, providing the author of the question the opportunity to fix the question, such that it becomes answerable.

So in effect, the two actions you describe aren't mutually exclusive; *you should do both*.  When a question doesn't contain enough information to be answered (in this case, because the example in question doesn't replicate the problem described) you should be closing the question for that exact reason, and also explain to the OP what the behavior of the provided sample is (if you think that would be helpful for them), so that they can work to improve their question such that it contains a reproducible example.

When a question doesn't contain enough information to be answered we don't want people *telling* the OP that the question is unanswerable *but not closing the question*.  If that were what we actually wanted people to do there would be no reason for closure to exist in the first place.

Comment: Not being able to reproduce the problem on my home PC doesn't mean the question is not answerable. I can see C++ undefined behavior even if the code works for me. If the error message given by op than fits to what the undefined behavior could cause, then I can perfectly answer the question.

Comment: @BDL Sure, that's a case where the OP *did* provide a sample capable of reproducing the problem, but you as the reader of that question didn't realize that they did.  That is always going to be a problem in questions where the behavior of the code is inherently inconsistent.  In such cases a reader needs to understand that they can't just run the code once and treat it as the only possible behavior of that snippet. That can require some domain knowledge.

Comment: In my book (assuming it's a normal question and not totally off-topic), a close-vote should be something the OP can rectify by improving the question. But if that sample actually produces that output on his machine, how could he possibly change his post to improve?

Comment: @nvoigt Typically the problem is that the OP is only providing a portion of what they were actually using to replicate the problem themselves, and didn't include the aspect of the program that is actually relevant to diagnosing the problem.  The solution for them is to figure out what they did and didn't include, and which, of the things they didn't include, do they need to add in order to reproduce the problem.  Of course the other possibility (which happens often enough) is that they have not accurately described what happens when they run their program.

Comment: @nvoigt But in those (in my experiences, quite rare) cases where the OP really has provided *everything* that they're doing, and provided an entirely accurate description of what happens, and no one else is still able to reproduce the problem, then the fact still remains that the question isn't answerable, so such a question probably just can't fit on SO as a platform.

Comment: @Servy: But you can't be sure why you can't reproduce: Could be different hardware, different drivers, different karma, or, what you seem to assume, missing code. But unless you are sure that it is a missing code problem, you shouldn't vote to close. That's like telling the op "Since I can't reproduce your problem on my PC, your question is stupid and your not allowed to ask it".

Comment: I think it's kinda presumptuous to declare that if **I** cannot fix it, **nobody can**. If I cannot fix it, I will walk away to the next question, not close-vote it. Somebody else might well be able to reproduce it and subsequently fix it.

Comment: @BDL If the question is related to the behavior of differing hardware or other factors outside of the code then it's not a *programming* question anymore, and it would probably belong on a different site, perhaps SF.  You should be voting to close the question when it doesn't contain the information needed to reproduce the problem, even if you don't know what is missing from the example in order to be able to reproduce it (because you almost never *can* know what is missing from the OP's question in order to make the example verifiable).

Comment: That the question doesn't contain enough information to reproduce the problem doesn't mean, "the OP is stupid", it just means, "we can't answer it".  There are lots of reasons why we might not be able to answer it, and plenty of them involve the OP not being stupid at all.  That the OP isn't able to provide enough information for others to reproduce the problem still doesn't change the fact that others still can't reproduce the problem, which is what the close reason is there for.

Comment: @Servy "If the question is related to the behavior of differing hardware or other factors outside of the code then it's not a programming question anymore" - If I read that literally, then nearly all the performance questions that trace back to hardware effects should be closed.

Comment: @nvoigt That's why we require 5 close votes, not just one.  It's also why we require people to have a certain amount of experience with the site to use the feature; people that we can trust to be reasonably reliable at judging whether or not they can't reproduce the problem described because the question is lacking sufficient information, or because they aren't skilled enough at evaluating the example provided.  It's also why questions are able to be reopened when closed, in the event that users later determine what needed to be done to reliably reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mysticial I suppose a more rigorous statement of that quote would be to point out that when discussing a programming problem tightly coupled with the behavior of a specific hardware setup that, at a minimum, the information about what the hardware setup is would need to be included as a part of "the information necessary to reproduce the problem".  Where the line is drawn between a programming problem that relies on specific hardware, from a hardware problem that isn't about the programming, is another topic for another day.

Comment: They point you don't seem to accept is that just because you can't reproduce it, it doesn't mean that it's not reproducible. For OpenGL it's quite common to produce different errors on an Intel GPU than on a NVIDIA GPU. Even if the op states what exactly they are using, I still can't reproduce unless I have the same hardware. But still I can usually tell what the problem might be. For me, a MVCE is reproducible when on OPs hardware, the exact same code as in the question (without adding anything) produces the problem.

Comment: @BDL If the OP has stated that they have a problem that manifests itself on a particular type of GPU, and you don't have one, then indeed, you aren't capable of verifying if the example presented does or doesn't replicate the problem.  We trust people casting close votes who aren't in a position of replicating the conditions described in the question as the necessary reproduction steps, to not close a question for this close reason, as they don't actually know if the example is complete/verifiable or not.

Comment: I think in a lot of cases, neither the OP nor the majority of the people viewing the question even realize that the hardware is relevant. So it gets left out of the question - at least until somebody with the right intuition asks for it.

Comment: Ok, my comment was unclear, sorry. What usually happens is that OP states on which hardware they work. But usually they are not able to know if the problem is caused by the hardware or by doing something wrong in the API. So the information that it works on my hardware is the first confirmation for me, op, and everyone else on the question, that the problem **is** caused by invoking undefined behavior and not by plain wrong code.

Comment: I already had a questions where the localization setting was causing the problem because an OS error message in that specific language was longer than the buffer it got stored. It is impossible to include all information that might be relevant for question beforehand. And I would say it's also unnecessary since 90% of the questions are not caused by such problems. If I have to include 100 lines of configuration information for a 5 line of code question just because it could be relevant sounds a bit like overdoing it.

Comment: @Mysticial So then the question was missing information necessary for reproducing the problem, and it needed to have that information added for it to become answerable.  What type of information is missing isn't relevant to whether or not the question is answerable.

Comment: @BDL You're entirely right that the OP simply *can't* include *all* of the information related to what they're actually doing.  What they *do* need to do is figure out which, of that enormous amount of information, is what is the *minimal* amount that is necessary to reproduce the problem.  Since the vast majority of that information won't be necessary to reproducing the problem, it doesn't need to be included.  When the OP misjudges what information is and is not necessary, the end result is a question that doesn't reproduce the problem.  The resolution is for the OP to add that information.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough. I look forward to seeing you close every single performance question I've ever answered. There's about 80 of them so please get to work.

Comment: @Servy: Fair enough. I look forward for you telling each OP to buy a second GPU to verify whether the GPU vendor makes a difference.

Comment: @BDL Obviously everyone isn't going to accurately judge what information is and isn't necessary to reproduce the problem every time.  The point is that if they fail, and *don't* provide enough information to reproduce the problem, the question needs to be closed, until the OP can figure out what their question was missing to make it reproducible.  If their code is GPU related, and they suspect that their code may depend on vendor-specific behavior, that may mean mentioning their GPU vendor in the question.

Comment: @Mysticial So you're saying you make it a habit of trying to answer questions without actually having enough information to know what the problem is?  That does indeed sound problematic.