# After new information, the question is too narrow. What should I do?

Tags: discussion

The question below, which looked interesting, after some new information, pinpoints the problem on an external program running on the same machine. That program will very likely never be identified by a user (me) who hasn't got sufficient privileges to debug such a machine.

*[Java Scheduler Time Drift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571647/java-scheduler-time-drift)*

The question should be closed as its scope is now too narrow, correct? Unfortunately, I can't see that option any more.

Comment: There's no _too narrow/too localized_ close reason. I'm not sure what you want to discuss. Narrow and localized questions are okay, as long as they're well-defined. The only half-applicable close reason I can think of is _not reproducible_.

Comment: It's your question, and there are no answers. You can just delete it if you think it's not useful for SO.

Comment: You should ask the company to help you debug the problem.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that question, you merely need somebody that dug into that problem before.  That requires as many eyes as you can possibly get on that question, be prepared to put a bounty on it.  Do avoid theorizing about the reason, everybody will flip their mental switch when you talk about AV and that only ever produces close-votes.  It is not AV.

Comment: I think your conclusion is actually incorrect - I don't think it pinpoints the problem on an external program at all, but instead highlights (at its core) how hardware & OS differences between systems can result in `nanoTime()` and system time not lining up. That makes it a very useful and interesting question, IMHO. Please don't close it.

Comment: @MichaelBerry going to remove my conclusion. Your answer is by far the most comprehensive and interesting answer I've ever gotten on SO. Many thanks!

Comment: Really related: [Should we close-vote questions that we cannot reproduce on our machines?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364314/should-we-close-vote-questions-that-we-cannot-reproduce-on-our-machines) Most answers say don't close (which contradict to the answer here)

Answer (score 8):

In the end, it was discovered that the program being run on Windows 7 was the main reason for the perceived problem, so this situation was pretty much solved. Nevertheless, the following paragraphs describe a position on what to do when problem is yet not reproducible.

---

The first edit of the linked question added the following paragraph:

> **Update:** following Slaw's comment I tried on multiple different hardware. What I found is that this issue doesn't manifest on any personal hardware. Only on the company one. On company hardware it also manifests on Win10, though an order of magnitude less. My bet is that some monitoring software / AV / etc messes up with windows clock, specific with the `nanos`. Why, no idea, but this new information turns the problem as an isolated event and thus not really that interesting.

This means that there is a specific machine that reproduces the problem, yet not enough details were given about that particular machine that would enable other people to reproduce it. Without that, the question is not useful to future readers, and should therefore be closed for lacking a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), at least until the OP (in this case, you) figures out what's missing. Although the close reason only mentions "code", the environment that triggers the issue is still a very relevant part of the MCVE¹ all the same.

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are *not useful to other readers*.

---

With that said, it is understandable to question whether, in a case such as this one, we should wait for the missing piece of the MCVE or vote to close as soon as possible. Usually, we are advised to *vote to close immediately* [[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close/98026)]. For the specific case of problems which are significantly harder to reproduce, we have at least one [diverging opinion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364314/1233251). Emphasis on Tim Post's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364324/1233251):

> You should cast a close vote in these cases only if you feel that *not doing so would result in someone else likely wasting their time*. There's no real blanket flowchart sort of answer to it other than use your best judgement based on your knowledge of the language being used.

In other words, this challenges us to make a wise decision, based on our knowledge of the problem and the underlying technologies, on whether a question with a sub-complete MCVE should stay open or not, which is fairly reasonable. While I do not wish to carve my own statement in stone here, I may note that even a closed question can receive comments that can guide the OP towards the missing piece.

Comment: You might note that this is located in `should be closed->off topic`.

Comment: "not enough details were given about that particular machine" Just out of curiosity: how many details would be deemed reasonably sufficient in such a case? Would OS, list of installed software, hardware configuration be enough?

Comment: @Trilarion The usual investigation process of creating an MCVE apply, I suppose. By "enough details", I do not mean to aimlessly throw in every factor one may think of for the sake of completeness, but to work it over and include details when they are requested. Like other minimal examples, we usually expect an isolated problem statement that needs to be discovered before the question is well-formed. This case is particularly tricky, considering that the attempts at isolating the problem have not succeeded so far.

Comment: "to work it over and include details when they are requested" Does it mean that the question in the current state should stay open or should it be closed? The asker did kind of work it over and seems to be willing to provide details should they be requested.

Comment: @Trilarion If it doesn't have enough details, It should be closed. That does not prevent it from being improved over time.

Comment: Okay, but then I still would not know which details would be necessary for it to have to remain open? Shouldn't we be able to clearly say what we expect from a question like this`to be on-topic?

Comment: @Trilarion I'm afraid not. There is no golden rule for the amount or kind of detail that should be in a question. We generally ask for an MCVE because if no one is able to reproduce the problem as presented, the question cannot be useful to future readers.